# netbeans: call on of database field into label based on selected combobox item

Tags: java, swing, jdbc

I have created my database schema. The main purpose is to find a simple coding to call one of database field based on my selected combo box 
this is my current coding

```
database: purnamajaya
field : Kodebarang,Namabarang,Harga,Stock,Tanggal
```

so wanted to change my label into Harga based on a selected item on combo box(my combo box is linked to Nama Barang on the database)

I'm a newbie here so I don't really understand how this ctrl+k works sorry

[image]

Comment: call one of* sorry typo

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stackoverflow, please add the code as text rather than pasting images, you can format the post with code blocks

Comment: And if you find a typo, then **edit** your question, don't post a comment with a correction.

Comment: first i thought that those 2 notif were life saver , who knows 1 with 10k reput 1 with 56k reput come with nothing but only to tell me a pity newbie to correct my small mistake , true sad what happen to this platform god.